# Object spread with common keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider this:

```
let obj1 = {id: 1, common_key: "one", property1: "property_one"}
let obj2 = {id: 1, common_key: "two", property2: "property_two'"}

let merged = {...obj1, ...obj2}
console.log(merged)
```

Output:

```
{id: 1, common_key: "two", property1: "property_one", property2: "property_two'"}
```

We see that `common_key` from `obj2` is taken over (value - `"two"`) in this merge.
Does this mean where when there is a collision of common key in an object spread (merge) it is guaranteed that the one that come later wins? If yes, is this mentioned somewhere in ES6 spec?

Comment: It's just the sequence of order, and the fact that ids are not repeated.  The logic adds all the key values from the first object to the new object, and then it does the same with the second object.  Since keys are not duplicated, they replace anything that pre-exists.

Comment: Same way as if you wrote `var x = {'a': 1, 'a': 2 }`.  The value of `x.a` at the end would be 2

Comment: @Taplar- yes thats how someone would expect it logically, but I would be more comfortable if I see it mentioned somewhere in specs.. or do you think it is super obvious and wouldn't be mentioned explicitly in the specs?

Comment: Given that this is the behavior of objects, I wouldn't be surprised if it was not mentioned in the specs for basic objects.

Comment: Last override wins. Its the basic strategy of most programming languages.

Comment: don't know if it's in the spec but this behavior is 100% guaranteed always

Comment: Spec https://tc39.es/ecma262/2020/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation. You need to unwind `PropertyDefinition:...AssignmentExpression` part.

Comment: @Tintin Here is the MDN documentation about duplicate property names: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Duplicate_property_names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check this section in MDN doc, [Spread in object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals)

> The Rest/Spread Properties for ECMAScript proposal (ES2018) added spread properties to object literals. It copies own enumerable properties from a provided object onto a new object
>
> Shallow-cloning (excluding prototype) or merging of objects is now possible using a shorter syntax than `Object.assign()`
>
> ```js
> const obj1 = { foo: 'bar', x: 42 };
> const obj2 = { foo: 'baz', y: 13 };
>
> const mergedObj = { ...obj1, ...obj2 };
> // Object { foo: "baz", x: 42, y: 13 }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The [rest object spread is just syntactic sugar for  `Object.assign`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md)(with the exclusion of setters)

The spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.assign) states how `Object.assign(target, ...sources)` operates:

> 4. For each element `nextSource` of `sources`, in ascending index order, do

Where it basically does a `forEach` loop for each of the sources in **ascending** order => `Set`s each OwnProperty `key`/`value` to the `target` object(`to`).

MDN also mentions this in [§ Merging objects with same properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The properties are overwritten by other objects that have the same properties later in the parameters order.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

If you have common properties the priority will be right to left. The object the most at the right will have priority over the one at its left.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will always get the property of the *subsequent* object.

It doesn't directly mention that on MDN, but the spread operator applies a shallow comparison and assigns the subsequent property to the object.

https://dmitripavlutin.com/object-rest-spread-properties-javascript/#21-object-spread-rule-latter-property-wins

You can use the spread operator to create immutable objects this way

```js
let obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

let _obj = {...obj, three: 4};

console.log(_obj);
```

Output

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 4
}
```

---

---

---

And using multiple objects...

```js
let obj = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 }

let _obj = {...obj, three: 4};

_obj.four = 4;

let __obj = {...obj, ..._obj}

console.log(__obj);
```

Output

```
{
  "one": 1,
  "two": 2,
  "three": 4,
  "four": 4
}
```